# Using js and css of primary domain from subdomain

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, subdomain

Suppose I have a domain named example.com and now I am creating my mobile site with subdomain mobile.example.com.

mobile.example.com shows content of `http://example.com/mobile` directory.

example.com directory structure is

```
-- css
-- images
-- js |--- custom.js
-- mobile |--- start.html
-- html files
```

now I want to use custom.js in start.html file i.e. mobile.example.com/start.html

I cannot do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>
```

on start.html since it means `mobile.example.com/js/custom.js`, which is not available.

Also

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/custom.js"></script>
```

does not work as it also means `http://mobile.example.com/../js/custom.js`

Also I cannot do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Because other than example.com I have another domain for testing. I don't want to change my code while uploading into test server and prodserver.

Also I cannot copy the js/custom.js into example.com/mobile folder because it will bring redundancy.

Any other ideas how I can redirect my js and css request to primary domain?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot copy contents from original path then create symbolic links. Do this from `mobile/` directory:

```
ln -s ../js .
ln -s ../css .
ln -s ../images .
```

Then use them as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: cool it worked in my server which got linux machine but for my windows machine where I am using xampp for development, it is still a problem.

Comment: Yes `ln` doesn't work for Windows. [On Windows you can use `junction` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)

Comment: There is also [Linux Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)

Comment: If you're using Windows Vista or later, you can also use the command `mklink`. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link#Tools

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, you can use kinda proxy:

```
/pxy.php?path=/js/custom.js
```

And in the `pxy.php`, you can add this:

```
<?php
    die (file_get_contents("http://example.com" . $_GET["path"]));
?>
```

Comment: sorry I am not using php in my project

Comment: But you could use another server side code if you want go with this solution. Not a bad idea